# p.458 of Wade's Introduction to Analysis (4th edition)

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Suppose that $V$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and that $\phi:V \to \mathbb R^n$ is injective and $C^1$ on $V$ with $\Delta_{\phi}\neq 0$.

The second line of the proof of Wade p.458 Theorem 12.10 says "By Lemma 11.39, the set $\phi(E^{\circ})$ is open [in $\mathbb R^n$], $\dots$"

[Lemma 11.39: Let $V$ be open and nonempty in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $f:V \to \mathbb R^n$ be continuous. If $f$ is $1-1$ and has first-order partial derivatives on $V$, and $\Delta_f \neq 0$ on $V$, then $f^{-1}$ is continous on $f(V)$.]

(Since $\phi$ is continuous), by Lemma 12.9 $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous on $\phi(V)$. Since $E^{\circ}$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$ and we do not know whether $\phi(V)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, I think it only follows (by p.322 Theorem 9.26) that $\phi(E^{\circ})=(\phi^{-1})^{-1}(E^{\circ})$ is relatively open in $\phi(V)$.

Please let me ask how it can be said that "the set $\phi(E^{\circ})$ is open (in $\mathbb R^n$)".

Comment: It can be shown that $\phi (V)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$ (see Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds p.65 Theorem 8.2). It follows that $\phi (E^{\circ})$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$.